# Xcode swift link to facebook page

Tags: xcode, facebook, swift

I have an app with a button that is suppose to open a Facebook page.  It checks to see if the user has Facebook installed and should open the page in the app.  If it is not installed, then it simply opens the page with Safari.  It is not working however.  I suspect it has something to do with the wrong address for it, if the user has Facebook installed:

```
var fbUrl = NSURL(string: "fb://facebook.com/FacebookPageName")!
var fbUrlWeb = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookPageName")!

if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(fbUrl)) {
  // Facebook App installed
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fbUrl)
} else {
  // No Facebook App installed
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fbUrlWeb)
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is with the format of your Facebook url so notice the format. I use this extension to open urls. You provide it with an array of urls in the order you want them to try to be opened and it tries the first one first and if it fails it goes to the second one and so on:

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func tryURL(urls: [String]) {
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        for url in urls {
            if application.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: url)!) {
                application.openURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for use:

```
UIApplication.tryURL([
            "fb://profile/116374146706", // App
            "http://www.facebook.com/116374146706" // Website if app fails
            ])
```

[Update] for Swift 4:

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func tryURL(urls: [String]) {
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        for url in urls {
            if application.canOpenURL(URL(string: url)!) {
                application.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
UIApplication.tryURL(urls: [
                "fb://profile/116374146706", // App
                "http://www.facebook.com/116374146706" // Website if app fails
                ])
```

[Update] for iOS 10 / Swift 5

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func tryURL(urls: [String]) {
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        for url in urls {
            if application.canOpenURL(URL(string: url)!) {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    application.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
                else {
                    application.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm totally new to this. How do I add an extension?  I cut and pasted what you wrote and it caused an internal crash in Xcode.

Comment: Just make a new swift file import Foundation and UIKit and then paste the extension. Extensions are placed outside the scope of any class.

Comment: Great thank you!  I just need to figure out how to get my Facebook page ID.

Comment: Used an online tool and got the ID.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to generate Facebook page ID programmatically without any online tool ?

Comment: FYI, code may need updating? `'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead`

Comment: Remember to add this to your plist:
`<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>fb</string>
 </array>` otherwise you'll get the error "this app is not allowed to query for scheme fb" when trying to open a "fb://" url..

Comment: @Wiingaard How to open a Page? The above code is for Profile

Comment: @VaibhavJhaveri Same.. Using `profile` also opens pages, I believe..

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func tryURL(urls: [String]) {
            let application = UIApplication.shared
            for url in urls {
                if application.canOpenURL(URL(string: url)!) {
                    //application.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
                    application.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And for use:

```
UIApplication.tryURL(urls: [
            "fb://profile/116374146706", // App
            "http://www.facebook.com/116374146706" // Website if app fails
            ])
```