# How to open fb and instagram app by tapping on button in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, instagram

How can I open Facebook and Instagram app by tapping on a button in `swift`? Some apps redirect to the Facebook app and open a specific page. How can I do the same thing?

I found it:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/de/app/x-gift/id839686104?mt=8&uo=4")

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

but I have to know the app `URL`. Other examples were in `ObjectiveC`, which I don't know =/

Comment: Please include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) in your post.

Comment: @A-Live I did update my question

Comment: Funny how you use my app's app-store link :D

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Take a look at these links, it can help you:

https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

[Open a facebook link by native Facebook app on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416338/open-a-facebook-link-by-native-facebook-app-on-ios)

Otherwise, there is a quick example with Instagram for opening a specific profile (nickname: johndoe) here:

```
var instagramHooks = "instagram://user?username=johndoe"
var instagramUrl = NSURL(string: instagramHooks)
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramUrl!) {  
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramUrl!)
} else {
  //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://instagram.com/")!)
}
```

Comment: but what about youtube? How can I use it? `youtube://channel/channel_code`? I did it and it doesn't show me my channel

Comment: As the answer should've pointed to you, when you have such a question you need to look for API of the youtube app (or any other app you are interested in). Alternatively you can download the app and check its info.plist to research available app url schemes, but only if there's no documentation as this might not be supported across all versions.

Comment: @A-Live I looked at API Documentation, but nothing here about iPhone hooks

Comment: Swift 4 version:
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:yourUrl)!) {
            UIApplication.shared.open( URL(string: yourUrl)!, options: [:])
        } else {
            //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
            UIApplication.shared.open( URL(string: yourUrl)!, options: [:])
        }

Comment: The top two links you provided are dead.

Answer (score 46):

> Update for Swift 4 and iOS 10+

OK, there are two easy steps to achieve this in Swift 3:

First, you have to modify `Info.plist` to list `instagram` and `facebook` with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Simply open `Info.plist` as a Source Code, and paste this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

After that, you can open `instagram` and `facebook` apps by using `instagram://` and `fb://`. Here is a complete code for instagram and you can do the same for facebook, you can link this code to any button you have as an Action:

```
@IBAction func InstagramAction() {

    let Username =  "instagram" // Your Instagram Username here
    let appURL = URL(string: "instagram://user?username=\(Username)")!
    let application = UIApplication.shared

    if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
        application.open(appURL)
    } else {
        // if Instagram app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
        let webURL = URL(string: "https://instagram.com/\(Username)")!
        application.open(webURL)
    }

}
```

For `facebook`, you can use this code:

```
let appURL = URL(string: "fb://profile/\(Username)")!
```

Answer (score 12):

In swift5, use this

```
   guard let instagram = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/yourpagename") else { return }
   UIApplication.shared.open(instagram)
```

Comment: Please vote this up. Universal URLs should be the preferred way now.

Comment: I agree with @thetrutz. I've tried this with Instagram Profile,Post,IIGTV and Reel URL (Swift5, SwiftUI)

Answer (score 9):

You actually don't need to use a web and app URL anymore. The web URL will automatically open in the app if the user has it. Instagram or other apps implement this on their end as a [Universal Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html?utm_source=revxblog)

**Swift 4**

```
func openInstagram(instagramHandle: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://instagram.com/\(instagramHandle)")  else { return }
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In swift 3;

First you should add this on your Info.plist

[image]

Than you can use this code;

```
    let instagramUrl = URL(string: "instagram://app")
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramUrl!)
    UIApplication.shared.open(instagramUrl!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 7):

**In swift 4:**

> Just change **appURL** and **webURL** :

```
twitter://user?screen_name=\(screenName)

instagram://user?screen_name=\(screenName)

facebook://user?screen_name=\(screenName)
```

> - 'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0:

```
let screenName =  "imrankst1221"
    let appURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://user?screen_name=\(screenName)")!
    let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/\(screenName)")!

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(appURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL as URL)
        }
    } else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(webURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(webURL as URL)
        }
    }
```

Comment: best answer for this question.

Answer (score 6):

Based on accepted answer here is the way to do this more elegantly with Swift 4

```
UIApplication.tryURL([
        "instagram://user?username=johndoe", // App
        "https://www.instagram.com/johndoe/" // Website if app fails
        ])
```

And truly remember to add the scheme to allow the app to open. However even if you forget that instagram will open in Safari.

The tryUrl is an extension similar to presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376811/704803

Comment: `tryURL` is not a Swift 4 feature... it's an extension you added (probably similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376811/704803)

Comment: @andrewtweber you are right! How could I have missed that :( Added your suggestion to the answer itself.

Answer (score 5):

### SwiftUI Version

### Add in Info.plist

First, you have to modify `Info.plist` to list `instagram` and `facebook` with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Simply open `Info.plist` as a Source Code, and paste this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

When you want to open the Facebook App and direct to a Facebook-Page, use the Page-ID. Here is a Link, where you could find them: https://www.facebook.com/help/1503421039731588

### Schemes

> fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile **OR** pages
>
> fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list
>
> fb://notifications – Open Facebook app to the notifications list *(NOTE: there appears to be a bug with this URL. The Notifications page opens. However, it’s not possible to navigate to anywhere else in the Facebook app)*
>
> fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed
>
> fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page
>
> fb://requests – Open Facebook app to the Requests list
>
> fb://notes – Open Facebook app to the Notes page
>
> fb://albums – Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list
>   Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416399/8642838

### SwiftUI-Code Version

```
    Button(action: {
        let url = URL(string: "fb://profile/<PAGE_ID>")!
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        // Check if the facebook App is installed
        if application.canOpenURL(url) {
            application.open(url)
        } else {
            // If Facebook App is not installed, open Safari with Facebook Link
            application.open(URL(string: "https://de-de.facebook.com/apple")!)
        }
    }, label: {
        Text("Facebook")
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For opening instagram or facebook pages from your app, It worked for me
just to use links like [www.facebook.com/user](http://www.facebook.com/user) , or [www.instagram.com/user](http://www.instagram.com/user)

The instagram and facebook apps opened automatically when doing this.

Comment: This depend on device settings, it could also open the browser, in your case, your device already remember that you want to view those sites in their respective apps.