# redirect to the facebook app when I click share button in swift webview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webview, uiwebview

I have a WebView app in my iPhone but I want when I click in share button in google+ and Facebook I would like to open it in Facebook app *when installed,when not in safari )but another links to open all in web view just from Facebook and google+ \
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!





static let LOAD_FROM_URL = true






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if ViewController.LOAD_FROM_URL {
        // URLからロードする
        if let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/") {  // TODO: URLを指定する
            let req = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
            self.webView.loadRequest(req)
        }

    }

}






func WebView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    // [SDK] 広告クリックの時の処理を行う
    if !WebView(webView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest: request, navigationType: navigationType) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Have a look at this: [How to open fb and instagram app by tapping on button in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902534/how-to-open-fb-and-instagram-app-by-tapping-on-button-in-swift)

1st links on Google. Or are you looking for something different ?

---

**EDIT:** You asked me how to make the button trigger an event, here' how:

1) Open the Assistant editor by using ALT-CMD-ENTER.

2) Create an IBAction from your button by CTRL dragging from the button to your code:

3) Put the necessary code in your IBAction, for example:

```
@IBAction func Fb(sender: UIButton) {

        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
            let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

            self.presentViewController(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: something like this but when i am not so good in iOS Xcode i don t know how can i do this can you help me

Comment: @TonTonii Did you have a look at the links of that answer ? I am not going to copy paste here something that has already been written elsewhere :P

Comment: i trap it but the Facebook open automatically when i start the app and nothing hempen when i am taping in button

Comment: @TonTonii Sorry, I don't understand what you have just written :/

Comment: something in so I'm looking for. but the safari; opens automatically when I open my app and when I press the button that opens in my webview I am net so well in ios

Comment: @TonTonii I am really sorry, I try my best, but I cannot decipher your comment :(

Comment: I have a webview app with swift. I would like to tap of the buttons the facebook app opens. but that does not happens. did you have some codes that can help me to do this.I'm not good at building of IOS APP

Comment: @TonTonii Now I understand you (I think). Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot theta work great

Comment: @TonTonii Happy I could help :D

Comment: I dont touch SLComposeViewController since objective c, thank you +1