# How to open an external app using bundle identifiers such as com.whatsapp or com.facebook.Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift

i need to open an external app from my app, my backend give me data like `com.whatsapp` or `com.facebook.Facebook` etc .

when I look for this on the internet , it suggests answers using url scheme like whatsapp:// .. but it is not what I need.

this is my code

```
func openApp(app : String) {

        if let url = URL(string: app),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        } else {
            customAlert(title: "error", message: "Failed to open \(app)")
        }



    }
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

Comment: on iOS platform, it is only allowed to open third party app from your app using URL schemes. There is no other way. If you try to manipulate it then you may face rejection in App Store approval process.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902534/how-to-open-fb-and-instagram-app-by-tapping-on-button-in-swift