# Opening up facebook app page when button is pushed. Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, plist, deep-linking

Facebook app wont open up, facebook in safari opens instead. Using xCode 10.2.1

Deployment target running iOS 12.2

Edit: this code does achieve the desired objective for Instagram

Edit2: So on @bbrodsky's recommendation i changed "facebook" to "fb" in the URL link. The problem now is that it opens to my personal feed and not the business page i want it to open to.

Edit3: So ive gotten it to work. Opens up the facebook app, and goes to desired page. Had to change the appURL to "fb://profile/NUMERICFBID". I was able to get the numeric facebook ID for the page at this site https://findmyfbid.com/

Tried solutions from this post and others. Cant seem to find any recent answers to this question, as everything seems to be from earlier versions of iOS and swift/xCode. Unsure if things have changed. Have added the recommended code to the plist source file with no results.

[How to open fb and instagram app by tapping on button in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902534/how-to-open-fb-and-instagram-app-by-tapping-on-button-in-swift)

```
@IBAction func facebookButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let screenName =  "MYSCREENNAME"
   let appURL = NSURL(string: "facebook://user?screen_name=\ 
     (screenName)")!
   let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://facebook.com/\ 
     (screenName)")!

   if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(appURL as URL, options: 
            [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } 
            else { UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL as URL)
            }
        } 
   else {
            //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have 
              Instagram
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(webURL as URL, options: 
                [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } 
            else {UIApplication.shared.openURL(webURL as URL)
            }
        }
```

expected result is that the facebook app opens to the particular page. keep getting this error code.

2019-06-08 11:28:39.561051-0500 SocialMediaLinkPractice[9888:2173963] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "facebook://user?screen_name=MYSCREENNAME" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme facebook"

Comment: Why do you create the URLs as `NSURL` and then cast them to `URL` everywhere you use them? Why not just create them as `URL` in the first place?

Comment: Im just a beginner and working on a simple project and just copied the code. I dont even know what the difference between "NSURL" and "URL" is to be completely honest. Appreciate the input though. Ill mess around with changing it. @Fogmeister

Comment: No worries. Was just curious. For most cases when you see something with the `NS` prefix it is a legacy type from Objective-C. A lot of them now have their Swift equivalents that drop the `NS`. In your case just drop the NS and then you can remove the “as URL” bits.

Comment: Ahh i see. Yeah i had looked up the NS prefix before but didnt quite find anything that explained it like that. Thanks for the info. @Fogmeister

Answer (score 1):

### Add in Info.plist

First, you have to modify `Info.plist` to list `instagram` and `facebook` with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Simply open `Info.plist` as a Source Code, and paste this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

When you want to open the Facebook App and direct to a Facebook-Page, use the Page-ID. Here is a Link, where you could find them: https://www.facebook.com/help/1503421039731588

### Schemes

> fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile **OR** pages
>
> fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list
>
> fb://notifications – Open Facebook app to the notifications list *(NOTE: there appears to be a bug with this URL. The Notifications page opens. However, it’s not possible to navigate to anywhere else in the Facebook app)*
>
> fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed
>
> fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page
>
> fb://requests – Open Facebook app to the Requests list
>
> fb://notes – Open Facebook app to the Notes page
>
> fb://albums – Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list
>   Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416399/8642838

### SwiftUI-Code Version

```
    Button(action: {
        let url = URL(string: "fb://profile/<PAGE_ID>")!
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        // Check if the facebook App is installed
        if application.canOpenURL(url) {
            application.open(url)
        } else {
            // If Facebook App is not installed, open Safari with Facebook Link
            application.open(URL(string: "https://de-de.facebook.com/apple")!)
        }
    }, label: {
        Text("Facebook")
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to open a specific profile on Facebook app, you have to use

```
let username = "your Facebook name"
let appURL = URL(string: "fb://profile/\(username)/?id=\(username)")!
```

otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use "fb://" and not "facebook://"

Comment: Awesome. that worked to open the app. But now its just opening to my feed and not the page i want it to open to. @bbrodsky

Comment: That worked. Had to find the facebook pages numeric ID which i did using this site. https://findmyfbid.com/

Really appreciate the help. Only small bug i have now is that if the facebook app was already on the intended page, clicking the link from my app just opens up the facebook app to a blank page with a search bar. Not too concerned about it really, but figured id write it here incase someone comes along with an easy fix.

Comment: @futureappguru glad i could help!