# Is there a way to link Facebook profiles using user IDs in app other than logging users in and the Facebook login button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I would like to create a link to a user's Facebook profile page so that others (within the app) can access the user's profile who is also a user of the app.

The login to the app is not via Facebook login necessarily and so I am looking for a way, if there is any, to get Facebook ID without forcing users to go through login flow using the login button.

I know how to get ID if user is logged into Facebook in "didCompleteWith result" method of Facebook login button and open a Facebook profile using schemes, as addressed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376673/xcode-swift-link-to-facebook-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199854/swift-open-facebook-profile-by-facebookuid).

But is there any way to get the ID without forcing users to login to Facebook?

Comment: No. And people who are not users of your app, should be none of your app’s business in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I don't think you have understood the question. I just simply want to allow people within the app to link their Fb profile for other people within the app; nothing to do with people who are not users. Added some hint in the explanation above to avoid the confusion.

Comment: So why do you not want them to login then?

Comment: @CBroe, just wondering if there's a way to avoid it , for simplicity and also, not having to log into social media when its not really necessary makes it easier for folks who are paranoid about their privacy, it's just facebook that I'm struggling on and I'm finding that actually facebook has some issues with Scheme Urls apparently! which is quite surprising .. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332195860270199