# Navigate to Facebook Page using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

The goal is simple, I want to allow a user to connect their Facebook page to the iOS app i've been developing so that when they press a button in my app, it will navigate them to the appropriate Facebook page. If the user has the Facebook app installed, it will launch and use the Facebook app and if not, it will use Safari.

I was able to implement this exact functionality for another app with the following code:

```
    if let facebookPageId = facebookPageIdTextField.text {
        let facebookHook = "fb://profile/" + facebookPageId
        if let url = URL(string: "\(facebookHook)") {
            
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/placeholder")!)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I had to browse the Facebook HTML source code in order to find the value to use for `facebookPageId` and asking a user to dive into the source code seems pretty impractical.

Does Facebook not want developers to have access to this kind of functionality? Has anyone found an easy fix for this?

Comment: Hi Justin, did you read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376673/xcode-swift-link-to-facebook-page)?

Comment: Although I appreciate the comment, this question is more tailored towards gathering the Facebook ID. I'm starting to thing that Facebook simply doesn't want to make this functionality easily accessible.